# How to execute shell command with parameters in groovy?

Tags: shell, groovy

I am trying to use shell command `notify-send -t 2000 "Title" "Message"` from groovy in next way `"notify-send -t 2000 \"Title\" \"Message\"".execute()` and it works perfect.
But when i am trying to put exprsession in place of message it seems nothing works. 
here is broken code below:

```
def todayDate = new Date()

def title = 'Title'
def message = " Message ${todayDate}"
println(title + message)
"notify-send -t 2000 \"${title}\" \"${message}\"".execute()
```

can you help me with understanding?

> Connected to the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:40305', transport: 'socket'
>   TitleFri May 06 13:41:43 CEST 2016
>   groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: execute for class: DUMMY
>       at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.unwrap(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:51)
>       at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoGetPropertySite.getProperty(PogoGetPropertySite.java:49)
>       at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callGroovyObjectGetProperty(AbstractCallSite.java:295)
>       at DUMMY$_closure1.doCall(DUMMY.groovy:1)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
>       at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
>       at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaMethod.invoke(ClosureMetaMethod.java:81)
>       at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:324)
>       at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1208)
>       at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1111)
>       at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1017)
>       at test.notification.run(notification.groovy:28)'

Comment: Is there an error message?

Comment: You can make it neater by using slashy strings: `/notify-send -t 2000 "${title}" "${message}"/.execute()` Also, you don't need to call `toString()` on message. But these are just decorations, what you say you have should work... Capture the output and show what it says

Comment: Sorry, but there is no output. it looks okay, but without notification window which should contains a text. You can have a look on expected result here [picture](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3xY1NHSe3DoazVTUDRaQmlYbVU/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: @tim_yates it seems groovy expected just one value, becouse if I am printing message, which is consist of one world(example 6May2016) it works ok and presenting notifications, otherwise (two or three words wrapped with ' or ") do nothing. :-(

Answer (score 3):

So the problem occurs when you have a space in your parameter.

So for example this will *not* work:

```
def command = "send_mail.sh \"Some text\""
command.execute();
```

`send_mail.sh` will receive 2 parameters instead of 1.

So to avoid problems split your string by arguments. So something like this:

```
def command = ["send_mail.sh", "Some text"];
command.execute();
```

First item (0 index) is a command and then arguments follow.

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare the command as a variable beforehand and then execute the command.

You can do it like this:

```
def todayDate = new Date().toString()
def title = 'Title'
def message = " Message ${todayDate.toString()}".toString()
println(title + message)
def command = "notify-send -t 2000 \"${title}\" \"${message}\""
command.execute()
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems this issue was mostly related to string formatting and  misunderstanding "Message 9 May 2016" as one String(argument).
For me it works in next way:

```
def command = new String[3]
command[0] = "notify-send"
command[1] = "Title"
command[2] = "\"Message ${todayDate}.toString()\"".toString()
def process = new ProcessBuilder(command).start()
```

Anyway, thanks to everyone.